# Can fiber channel cards be used to connect a Mac Pro server to our unmanaged switch?

Tags: network, mac-pro

(I've tried to research this, but I am a newbie when it comes to this topic, so my searches aren't quite yielding the most helpful results.)

Our company processes a lot of Mac Pros for resale, and many come with fiber channel cards that we have at our disposal. I've noticed that the 24 port unmanaged gigabit switch we use for mass net-restores has a fiber channel port. Could we use fiber to connect our Mac Pro netrestore server to the switch to get the highest possible throughput? We could use every little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a network switch then the fibre connection will not be for fibre channel, I'll be ethernet on fibre.  To switch fibre channel you need a fibre channel switch not a network switch.